# Developer tells me I can't use dropdown in this context

Tags: usability, design-patterns, interface, mobile-application

[image: dropbox2][image: a sort of dropdown or pop over by dropbox app for iPhone. HIG suggest to avoid pop overs for ipHone though, but it seems to be working here]
I have a question regarding the attached picture, where I can choose one or more lines on screen 1 and make my choice on screen 2 allowing the "next" button to become available (in screen 1 it is gray because, in order to proceed, you must choose one or more options); As a result, in screen 3 I have an array of options and I start my session in screen 4, when I tap on option "30" and "start" becomes available (again, "start" is gray in screen 3 because you must select an option).

question 1: would you use an alert or any other warning panel that tells you that you MUST select something if you try to tap the gray status of "next" and "start"?

question 2: Developer says that I cannot have a situation like that, is either full screen or an action sheet. Is that correct? Really an option panel that act as a dropdown (screen 3 and 4) cannot be implemented? I have seen this kind of panel before without going full and used it as a solution here, but I can't remember where right now (I don't think an action sheet is the right choice in this context btw).

Any thoughts? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Sorry if my explanation is a bit sloppy, I am still learning.

Comment: be wary when a dev says that it "can't" be done.

Comment: what do you mean? You're suggesting there's always a valid reason or, instead, it may be a fast 'can't be done' so it is always worthy to explore options? At least for personal culture (which is why I visit forums). Thank you

Comment: @jezmck you're right hahah! However, in this specific case it's not like it can't be done, but it SHOULDN'T be done, so this time devs win

Comment: okidok, I can't always win :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your app seems to be for iOS check this link:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/pickers/

Since you are talking about a filter i recommend you to go with a full screen solution, as you can see here:

[image]

If you replace apply with "start" you also don't need to show the "Start" option in the upper right anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have the Start in the upper right corner because it is a pattern throughout the app. Do you still think it is better to have an exception here? kind regards

Comment: I think consistency is more important, so if you are using this pattern already then stick to it and keep the start option in the top-right corner.

BUT since your developing an iOS application you should serve the users patterns that they already know since its easier for the users to navigate throughout your app this way. (not saying your pattern is wrong, im not 100% familiar with current iOS patterns).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is something that I have seen in native iOS Apps, such as Health or App Store. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I agree with the "modal" filter picker sheet. Since the user cannot proceed without selecting something here it makes sense to just take away everything else until they make that choice.

Comment: what are your thoughts about the screenshot I just added to the post by dropbox? It shows a similar situation, but it is not really a filter, only a sort of action sheet, I don't know what is the advantage of using a overlay panel instead of a full screen view. Dropbox has regular actionsheet throughout its app.